# Unity List every object added appears to be the same item when they should be different...?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, dynamic

currently I am trying to make a dynamic list that for game I am creating, basically creates a diamond pattern as shown here.

[image]

and i want to be able to hold the location of those objects inside of an array/list however as you see the lengths of each column are different sizes so i thought a list would work better then an array (but if you have an dynamic array tips please help). however when i add the object to my list through a for loop, I end up with the same exact object copied over and over in the list even though i change it after i add it to the list.

```cs
void Start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < colNum; i++){ //Cycle through columns of numbers 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
            climbColumn.Add(new List<GameObject>()); //Create a 2D array list
            if( i < colNum/2){ //Check that you are in the first half of the columns
                for(int c = 0; c < ((i * 2) + gameLength) ; c++){  //cycle through rows (2 has 3 rows in a regular game, 3 has 5 rows in a regular game... etc)
                   SpawnClimbSpots(i,c);
                }
            }else{
                for(int c = 0; c < (-2 * i + 20 + gameLength) ; c++){ //cycle through rows (12 has 3 rows in a regular game, 11 has 5 rows in a regular game... etc)
                   SpawnClimbSpots(i,c);
                }
            }
            
        }
       
        dice = new Die[] //Create 4 dice
        {
            new Die(tempObj),  new Die(tempObj),  new Die(tempObj),  new Die(tempObj)
        };
         for(int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++){ //assign the 4 die with the proper gameobjects.
            if(dice[i].dieGameObject.tag == "Untagged"){
                dice[i].dieGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Die" + (i + 1));
            }
         }
    }
    void SpawnClimbSpots(int i, int c){
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(climbSpot); //create new temp object for climbspot
         if( i < colNum/2){ //Check that you are in the first half of the columns
                    
                    climbColumn[i].Add(temp); //add to list
                    climbColumn[i][c].name = (i.ToString()+c.ToString());
                    climbColumn[i][c].transform.Find("Number").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numSprites[i];
                   //temp.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numSprites[i];
                    climbColumn[i][c].transform.position = new Vector2 (gameObject.transform.position.x - 10 + (i * 2), gameObject.transform.position.y + 1.5f - (c*1 - i) * 1.5f); //set position of newly created object
                    Instantiate(climbColumn[i][c]);//create object
                  
         }else{
                    climbColumn[i].Add(temp);//add to list
                    climbColumn[i][c].name = (i.ToString()+c.ToString());
                    climbColumn[i][c].transform.Find("Number").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numSprites[i];
                    climbColumn[i][c].transform.position = new Vector2 (gameObject.transform.position.x - 10 + (i * 2), gameObject.transform.position.y + 1.5f  - (c*1 + i - 10)* 1.5f );//set position of newly created object
                    Instantiate(climbColumn[i][c]); //create object
         }
    }
```

So far ive tried making the 'temp' object inside its own function so a new one is created each time the forloop runs, but that didnt help. and i have ran out of ideas to solve it.

Thanks for any help you can give! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying a **reference**! `GameObject` is a **class** so with the line

```
GameObject temp = climpSpot;
```

you are **NOT** as you think `create new temp object for climpSpot`!

Instead now `temp` and `climpSpot` refer to one and the same `GameObject`.

---

I think instead you would rather want to **first** create the new object and then add it to according collection

```
GameObject temp = Instantiate(climpSpot);
```

And remove the other `Instantiate` calls.

---

Also note that your `if -else` blocks are so similar that you should merge them together and only use a check for the one line that actually differs between them:

```
climpColumn[i][c].transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x - 10 * (i + 2), transform.position.y + 1.5f - (i < colNum/2 ? c - i : c + i - 10) * 1.5f;
```

Comment: Awesome I changed that line of code and it worked perfectly! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tyler you thank someone by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer; doing this marks your question as answered. Putting “(SOLVED)” in the title does not mark the question as answered.